# Selecting the path from the Registry using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, path, location, registry

I am getting the path of software from registry (Name) and can point to the path or further into the path but not able to select in backward

```
PS C:\Users\stars> (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SRH Systems\Stars\Data Manager'-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Rootpath +"Root"

C:\ProgramData\SRH Systems\STARS\Root
```

Or 
With `no +"Root"`

```
PS C:\Users\stars> (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SRH Systems\Stars\Data Manager'-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Rootpath 

C:\ProgramData\SRH Systems\STARS\
```

But what I want to get to is going back in the path

```
C:\ProgramData\SRH Systems
```

Command
[image]
Reg path
[image]

Comment: the `Split-Path` cmdlet has a `-Parent` parameter that will return the parent path of the input path. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks Lee Dailey ... It resolved the issue

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]